# Having a issue out putting a string from a array index for a random output

Tags: java

Having a issue outputting a string from a array index for a random sentence  output. The hashmap is fine grabs how many of each string in the array however once it has all the info give a int display of the items. Objective is to have user select form items after that select options for Subject - Verb - Adjective - Object - Adverb then do a random output.
also for some reason when it hit the adverb it is having the user input info before stated.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package shoutbox;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author alden
 */
public class Shoutbox {

    /**
     *
     */
    public int t;
    public int o;
    public int r;
    public int q;
    public int p;
public String subjectArray[]=new String[t]; // Intilized array by the size of int y
public String verbArray[]=new String[o];
public String adjectiveArray[]=new String[r];
public String objectArray[]=new String[q];
public String adverbArray[]=new String[p];

public Shoutbox(){


}


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Boolean repeat = true;
        System.out.println(" Please select a option");

        HashMap <Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(); // starts the hashmap


        map.put(0,"Are you new to programming");
        map.put(1, "I think java is a good start");
        map.put(2, "It is easy to learn");
        map.put(3, "You tube is a great resource");
        map.put(4,"Most people start with hello world");
        map.put(5,"After this you learn Scanners and getter and setters");
        map.put(6,"Next is encapsulation");
        map.put(7,"After this is loops");
        map.put(8,"Once you get loops work on arrays");
        map.put(9,"Next you should look at objects");


        map.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
            // for loop for the display of has map
            int key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(key + " : " + value);
        });
char y;
while (repeat = true){  // gives options for y or n
System.out.println("Please enter a value");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
String s = map.get(n);
System.out.println(s);

System.out.println("Would you like to enter another value. y/n");
y = in.next().charAt(0);

            switch (y) {
                case 'y':
                    repeat = true;
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                    repeat = true; 
                    break;
                default:
                    repeat = false;
                    break;
            }
break;

}
String input1;

boolean loop = false;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.printf("How many subjects are there?");
int t = in.nextInt();
String subjectArray[]=new String[t];

System.out.printf("How many verbs are there?");
int o = in.nextInt();
String verbArray[]=new String[o];

System.out.printf("How many adjective are there?");
int q = in.nextInt();
String adjectiveArray[]=new String[q];

System.out.printf("How many adjective are there?");
int r = in.nextInt();
String objectArray[]=new String[r];

System.out.printf("How many adverbs are there?");
int p = in.nextInt();
String adverbArray[]=new String[p];

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // aanother scanner for more input

for(int subjectCount=0;subjectCount<t;subjectCount++){
subjectArray[subjectCount]= input.next();
    int tempSub= subjectCount+1;
System.out.printf("Subject "+tempSub);
 // Assigned users value to array 
}
int subjectIndex;
Random randt = new Random();
subjectIndex = randt.nextInt(+1);//for loop
// random word
//Stores and finds random subject
//System.out.println(subjectArray[subjectIndex]);

for(int verbCount=0;verbCount<o;verbCount++){
verbArray[verbCount]= input.next(); // Assigned users value to array
    int tempVerb= verbCount+1;
    System.out.printf("verb "+tempVerb);
    }
int verbIndex;
Random rando = new Random();
verbIndex = rando.nextInt(o); // random word
//


for(int adjectiveCount=0;adjectiveCount<r;adjectiveCount++){
adjectiveArray[adjectiveCount]= input.next(); // Assigned users value to array
    int tempAdj= adjectiveCount+1;
    System.out.printf("Adjective " + tempAdj);
}
int adjectiveIndex;
Random randq = new Random();
adjectiveIndex = randq.nextInt(r); // random word
//

for(int objectCount=0;objectCount<q;objectCount++){
objectArray[objectCount]= input.next(); // Assigned users value to array
    int tempObj= objectCount+1;
    System.out.printf("Object "+ tempObj);
}
int objectIndex;
Random randr = new Random();
objectIndex = randr.nextInt(q); // random word
//

for(int adverbCount=0;adverbCount<p;adverbCount++){
adverbArray[adverbCount]= input.next(); // Assigned users value to array
    int tempAd= adverbCount+1;
    System.out.printf("Adverb "+tempAd);
}
int adverbIndex;
Random randp = new Random();
adverbIndex = randp.nextInt(p);

input1 = (subjectIndex + " " + verbIndex +" "+ adjectiveIndex +" "+ objectIndex +" "+ adverbIndex); // adds all items togather for loop
while(loop = true){
System.out.println(input1);
break;
}

}}
```

Comment: Don't make new `Scanner`s all over the place.  Make one `Scanner` at the top of the program and use it wherever you need input.  That should address some of your I/O issues.

Comment: I changed it runs slightly faster still trying to gather strings from the arrays to output a random sentence is there a better way to do it then i am doing?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

In a couple of places you're writing `while (something = true) {... break; }`.  Obviously, you meant for the loop to run until `something` became equal to `true`, but instead you discovered that the loop was running forever and so added the quick fix of `break;` at the end.

The problem is that `=` is an **assignment**; the equality test is `==`.  You would have been OK if you had written:

```
 while (something == true)  { ... }
```

You could also write the shorter version

```
while (something) { ... }
```

Because `something` is a `boolean`, and thus already has its own value of `true` or `false` value, you don't need to test it against `true` (or `false`) to obtain the `boolean` condition your loop needs.  It's not actually wrong to write `something == true` or `something == false`, just more verbose than necessary.

**Suggestions:**

Your basic logic for picking words at random to form a sentence is basically good, but it needs to be untangled from the process of obtaining the word lists from the user, especially if you want to use that last loop to generate multiple random sentences.

Having obtained the random indices for the different word classes, you'll want to extract the corresponding words from the word lists to actually build the sentence; right now you're just printing out a "sentence" consisting of the indices themselves.

You don't need multiple `Random` objects; it's not particularly harmful, just extra unnecessary lines of code and a few wasted CPU cycles.